# Профайлер для Eclipse (плагин)

Tags: java, профилирование, ide, eclipse

Посоветуйте простой и хороший профайлер для Eclipse.

Comment: [Java профайлер][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/1212/

Answer (score 0):

Обычно, если разговор заходит о профайлинге под `Java`, то он тут же и заканчивается выбором [`VisualVM`,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) тем более, что присутствует интеграция в распространенные `IDE`.

*Хороший обзор можно почитать на [**хабре**.](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/61857/)*